# Can not run js file in IE 11 when using vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js

My web app works nicely in Chrome, FireFox, Edge but it does not call certain function when used in IE 11.

This is js file

```js
window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      outputText: '',
      waiting: false,
      inputText: '',
      dataResult: []
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getDataSample()
  },

  methods: {

    

  }
})
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv7Ie.jpg)

Comment: can you display the whole code and error info?

Comment: Some JS features as `promise`, `async` functions etc. are not available with IE11. You can check that on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=promise). Maybe it is the case with your code or with you html if it embed template litterals.

Comment: arrow functions aren't supported in ie11